# Create a new php object in an existing class

Tags: php, oop

I have attempted to do this before and I have received errors, however I am following a tutorial and the author has done it. Is it possible to include/ require another php class within an existing class and create a new object within a class e.g.

```
class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    function __construct() {
         require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
         $db = new Db_Connect();
         $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: http 500 server error

Comment: Should work. Please give us a [mcve].

Comment: go hunting for your `error_log` file and inspect it

Comment: error was as a result of a incorrect reference in one of the include statements, thanks so it is possible to create a instance of a new object within an existing class.

Answer (score 0):

error was as a result of a incorrect reference in one of the include statements, thanks so it is possible to create a instance of a new object within an existing class